# sklearn transformer for outlier removal - returning xy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to remove rows that are labeled outliers.  I have this partially working, but not in the context of a pipeline and I am not sure why.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X1, y1 = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=10, n_informative=5, n_classes=3)

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
import numpy as np


class IsolationForestOutlierRemover(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, contamination=0.05):
        self.contamination = contamination
        self.isolation_forest = IsolationForest(contamination=self.contamination)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.isolation_forest.fit(X)
        mask = self.isolation_forest.predict(X) == 1
        self.mask = mask
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        if y is not None:
            return X[self.mask], y[self.mask]
        else:
            return X[self.mask]

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        self.fit(X, y)
        return self.transform(X, y)


working = IsolationForestOutlierRemover().fit_transform(X1, y1)
working[0].shape
# 95 
working

# %%

pipelinet = Pipeline(
    [
        ("outlier_removal", IsolationForestOutlierRemover(contamination=0.05)),
        ("random_forest", RandomForestClassifier()),
    ]
)

notworking = pipelinet.fit(X1, y1)
notworking
```

Getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/mmann1123/Documents/github/YM_TZ_crop_classifier/4_model.py in line 10
      349 # %%
      351 pipelinet = Pipeline(
      352     [
      353         ("outlier_removal", IsolationForestOutlierRemover(contamination=0.05)),
      354         ("random_forest", RandomForestClassifier()),
      355     ]
      356 )
---> 358 notworking = pipelinet.fit(X1, y1)
     359 notworking

File ~/miniconda3/envs/crop_class/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py:406, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    404     if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    405         fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 406         self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    408 return self

File ~/miniconda3/envs/crop_class/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py:346, in BaseForest.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    344 if issparse(y):
    345     raise ValueError("sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported.")
--> 346 X, y = self._validate_data(
    347     X, y, multi_output=True, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE
    348 )
...
--> 185     array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186     return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187 else:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (2, 95) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your specific package versions, and I am not using `conda`, but I was able to replicate your problem and fix it.

`RandomForestClassifier` expects **two** arrays X and y for the `fit` method. After the outlier removal, the transformed X and y need to be passed to the next step in the pipeline, but your current transform method in the `IsolationForestOutlierRemover` class returns a **single** tuple when y is not None, which is causing the issue.

To fix this, you need to update the `Pipeline` to correctly pass the X and y to the `RandomForestClassifier`. There are a couple of ways to do this; I did it with overriding.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

class IsolationForestOutlierRemover(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, contamination=0.05):
        self.contamination = contamination
        self.isolation_forest = IsolationForest(contamination=self.contamination)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.isolation_forest.fit(X)
        mask = self.isolation_forest.predict(X) == 1
        self.mask = mask
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        if y is not None:
            return X[self.mask], y[self.mask]
        else:
            return X[self.mask]

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        self = self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        return self.transform(X, y)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ("outlier_removal", IsolationForestOutlierRemover(contamination=0.05)),
        ("random_forest", RandomForestClassifier()),
    ]
)

pipeline.fit(X1, y1)
```

One thing to note... `fit_transform` is used during the `fit` call of the `Pipeline` object from `sklearn`. `fit()` is also only called for the final estimator.

Comment: I'm still throwing the same error. What version of sklearn are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered is due to the shape mismatch between the input and output arrays in the transform method. You should return None along with X.
Here is the modified code.

```
def transform(self, X, y=None):
    if y is not None:
        return X[self.mask], y[self.mask]
    else:
        return X[self.mask], None
```